# Scraping noise, in sync with car speed

Tags: noise

2000 Nissan Sentra, 100K miles

Audio clip taken from inside the car:
https://vocaroo.com/i/s1JMhQ1vgd6E

A medium to high pitch scraping noise, definitely seems "rotational."  No big change in the noise if I step quickly on the brake or gas -- it just gets faster or slower as the car gets faster or slower (whether coasting or braking).  Sound quiet on the recording but is very audible in real life.

Should I be concerned about a noise like this if the goal is to drive 10-20 miles per week for a year and then get rid of the car?

Comment: Have you had any work done just before the noise appeared? Have you run over an object or hit the kerb and the noise started then?

Answer (score 2):

I find that scraping noises most commonly come from the brakes - either a stone trapped behind the stone-shield, or the low-pad warning tines. Jack up each wheel in turn and spin it by hand to identify which wheel it's coming from, then take the wheel off and investigate.

If it's the brake pads, remember to change the pads on both wheels on the same axle at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

In my case a similar noise originated from a broken drum (rear brake) return spring. It suddenly broke while driving and the car had to be towed to a shop and a new spring was fitted in a few hours. FWD car obviously. Definitely try raising the car on two jack stands, rotating each wheel and feeling for anything not normal (noise, hard spots, wobbling).

Comment: Cars can have drum brakes and be rear wheel drive or AWD...